# "$75.00" into "75.00" JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I am trying to simply remove the "$" from the string.

I get the price using this:

```
var currentPrice = $.trim($("#ProductPrice").text());
```

I am just unsure what to do from there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your issue, [you can accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863). Then you can also upvote one or several answers with the gray up-arrow.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
currentPrice = currentPrice.replace("$", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just with [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
currentPrice = currentPrice.replace(/\$/, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

If that is the standard format, and you do not want to use regex, You can use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$("#ProductPrice").text().slice(1);
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GbwMw/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way using [.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var newCurrentPrice = currentPrice.replace("$", ""); // value = 75.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the string will always be of the format `$75.00`, then try using `.substring()`:

```
currentPrice = currentPrice.substring(1);
```

[Here's some more info](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) on the `.substring()` method.

Comment: [Congratulations, you are always the fastest](http://jsperf.com/substrr52345345)

Comment: Haaha oh wow! The test case you set up is pretty sweet, thanks for that @Brian! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the dollar by 'nothing'.

```
currentPrice = currentPrice.replace(/\$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `$` with an empty string, `''`:

```
var currentPrice = $.trim($("#ProductPrice").text()).replace("$", "");
```